# How to list all expressions in Python PLY

Tags: python, ply

I'm using PLY and have written below expressions to match this kind of sample string '(A OR B OR C)'.

> ```
> expression : LPAREN KEYWORD AND KEYWORD RPAREN
>            | LPAREN KEYWORD OR KEYWORD RPAREN
>            | LPAREN KEYWORD AND KEYWORD AND KEYWORD RPAREN
>            | LPAREN KEYWORD OR KEYWORD OR KEYWORD RPAREN
>            | LPAREN KEYWORD AND KEYWORD AND KEYWORD AND KEYWORD RPAREN
>            | LPAREN KEYWORD OR KEYWORD OR KEYWORD OR KEYWORD RPAREN
>            | LPAREN KEYWORD AND KEYWORD AND KEYWORD AND KEYWORD AND KEYWORD RPAREN
>            | LPAREN KEYWORD OR KEYWORD OR KEYWORD OR KEYWORD OR KEYWORD RPAREN
>            | LPAREN KEYWORD AND KEYWORD AND KEYWORD AND KEYWORD AND KEYWORD AND KEYWORD RPAREN
>            | LPAREN KEYWORD OR KEYWORD OR KEYWORD OR KEYWORD OR KEYWORD OR KEYWORD RPAREN
> ```

I have no idea how to cover all cases so I have to list them as many as possible and I know that's not elegant.

Any ideas to optimize this expression? Thanks a lot.

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: @rici, I'm trying to cover all cases like 'A OR B OR C OR D OR E......'.

Comment: Have you looked at any example expression grammars? What do you think is special about your expressions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're using PLY in Python, you can parser this expression with this:

```
def p_condition(p):
    """ condition : LPAREN comparation RPAREN """


def p_comparation(p):
    """ comparation : KEYWORD operator KEYWORD
                    | comparation operator KEYWORD  """

def p_operator(p):
    """operator : AND
                | OR """
```

To understand it, read about BNF grammar, and the PLY [docs](http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/ply.html#ply_nn23)